# Progress Dialog blocking

Tags: java, android, dialog, progressdialog

Progress Dialog not showing up was solved by removing the blocking call.

My purpose is to download large amount of data from internet and keep the end user informed about download status, however I have to wait to the data to complete downloading for proceeding to the next step, and because of that I have to block the code from executing.

Blocking causes the progress dialog not to show up or freeze. I need tip for implementing those tasks the best way. Because my tasks are simple it seems for me to be overkill to implement task complete listener and I was wondering if there was any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:::

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        dialog.show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Showing dialog");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(T result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.d(TAG, "Dismissing dialog");
    }
```

Comment: Didn't help :( Updating the first post with whole task

Comment: remove  super.onPreExecute(); &  super.onPostExecute(result); then try

Comment: I figured the problem.. with call to .get() result i blocked the main thread from continuing.. Should i implement complete listener or is there some easier way to do this kinda blocking the code from execution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

dialog= ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "MessageYouWantToDisplay");

}       


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(T result) {

dialog.dismiss();

}
```

You call the class that extends AsycTask by typing:

```
 new NameOFClass().execute();
```

Try this first as a test and put a Thread.sleep() in you doInBackground method to understand how it works. And after that use it in your project with your true methods, data etc.